# How to get the value from ACE-Angular editor

Tags: angularjs

I am having problems on getting Ace code editor results from whatever I type on the code editor.

As you can see I set up my controller with all the functionalities
and options. The only thing that is not working is rendering the results from editor. Thank you in advance....

```
app.controller('AceCtrl', function ($scope) {

      $scope.modes = ['CoffeeScript'];
      $scope.mode = $scope.modes[0];

      $scope.aceOption = {
        mode: $scope.mode.toLowerCase(),
        onLoad: function (editor) { 
          // defaults 
          editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
           // options
           editor.setOptions({
            showGutter: true,
            showPrintMargin: false,
           });

          $scope.modeChanged = function () {
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + $scope.mode.toLowerCase());
          };

        }
      };

      //Runs every time the value of the editor is changed
        $scope.aceChanged = function(_editor){
          console.log('Ace editor changed');
          // Get Current Value
          var currentValue = _editor.getSession().getValue();
          // Set value
          _editor.getSession().setValue('This text is now in the editor');
        };
});


<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="AceCtrl">
  <section >
    <select ng-model="mode" ng-options="m for m in modes" ng-change="modeChanged()" autofocus="0"></select> 
    <div ui-ace="aceOption" ng-model="aceModel" class="ace_editor"></div>
  </section>
   <div ng-change="aceChanged" style="border:1px solid red; position:relative; width:50%; height:300px; float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do this in the onChange handler of ui-ace you could get the document from the editor's session and grab it's value:

```
editor.getSession().getDocument().getValue();
```

Reference: http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/#nav=api&api=document

Example code:

```
<div ui-ace="{
    onLoad: aceLoaded,
    onChange: aceChanged
}"></div>
<textarea id="ace_document">
    {{aceDocumentValue}}
</textarea>

$scope.aceLoaded = function(_editor) {
    $scope.aceSession = _editor.getSession();
};
$scope.aceChanged = function () {
    $scope.aceDocumentValue = $scope.aceSession.getDocument().getValue();
};
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9swlVY9JnIfOnbOAfXui?p=preview

But the easiest way is to assign the value to scope and use ng-model on the directive's element:

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('rootController', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.aceValue = 'Foobar';
    }
]);
```

Template:

```
<div ui-ace ng-model="aceValue"></div>
<textarea id="ace_document" ng-model="aceValue"></textarea>
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fbtzYDEqIQEwB6Ascm3s?p=preview

Comment: one last question. What i get is the data. What i want to get is the outcome of the code that I wrote. Here is the way to do it on javascript. editor.getSession().on('change', function () {
    view.contents().find('body').html(editor.getSession().getValue());
     });

Comment: That's really out of the scope of this question and this is not what the comments are meant for. I would just post a new question, something like "How do i compile the string value from angular's ui-ace to actual HTML" You'll see you'll get really lengthy answers if i'm correct, wouldn't fit in these comments ;)

Comment: @JosephCC, i was playing around with ui-ace myself and stumbled on a much easier way to do this. Kind of stupid i didn't think about that in the first place :( I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. You right that is easier, but what I am researching now is how do I compile different code languages. Hope I come with a solution soon. Thanks anyways.....